# How to list all resources without know the package name or filesystem path for jar files in Java 9

Tags: java, resources, classloader, java-9

in Java 7 & 8 I use to be able to do

```
URLClassLoader urlLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
for (URL u : urlLoader.getURLs()) {
    System.out.println("*************** url=" + url);
}
```

But in Java 9 the above gives an error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to java.base/java.net.URLClass
Loader
```

So how do I list all resources without knowing the package prefix or the filesystem path of the jar files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer I found is to provide an argument to getResources, of course means you know prefix of the path the resources are located

```
  ArrayList<URL> resources = new ArrayList<URL>();
  ClassLoader urlLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
  Enumeration<URL> eU = urlLoader.getResources("com");
  while (eU.hasMoreElements()) {
     URL u = eU.nextElement();
     JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(u.getFile().replace("file:/", "").replaceAll("!.*$", ""));
     Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();
     while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry jarEntry = e.nextElement();
        resources.add(urlLoader.getResource(jarEntry.getName()));
     }
  }
```

Comment: There is no guaranty that every class path component contains a `com` resource (directory). Besides that, why don’t you use `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`, the official way to get the class path since Java 1.0, still working in Java 9?

Comment: @Holger yes agreed in my case I know the package prefix im looking for so works for me...

Answer (score 0):

The [Java9 Release Note](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html) states this:

> The application class loader is no longer an instance of
>   `java.net.URLClassLoader` (an implementation detail that was never
>   specified in previous releases). Code that assumes that
>   `ClassLoader.getSytemClassLoader()` returns a `URLClassLoader` object will
>   need to be updated. Note that Java SE and the JDK do not provide an
>   API for applications or libraries to dynamically augment the class
>   path at run-time.

To [add to this from the mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jpms-spec-experts/2015-October/000163.html) there are few resource-lookup methods which include ways such as :

- A class in a named module can read its own resources via the [`Class::getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) method, which returns an `InputStream`. It can get a URL to one of its own resources via the [`Class::getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) method.  These methods will not locate resources in other named modules.
- The `ClassLoader::getResource*` methods do not locate resources in any
  *named* modules.
- All existing resource-lookup methods in [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and [`ClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) work as they do today for *resources on the classpath*.
- The new [`Module::getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) method can be
  used to read the resources of any named module, without restriction.

These choices provides a balance between both [resource encapsulation](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/reqs/#resource-encapsulation) and [readable artifact](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/reqs/#readable-artifacts) requirements on Jigsaw.

Answer (score -1):

Because of the move to modular architecture, the old approach for looking up class paths is no longer supported:

> The application class loader is no longer an instance of
>   URLClassLoader but, rather, of an internal class. It is the default
>   loader for classes in modules that are neither Java SE nor JDK
>   modules.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm

You can try to parse the classpath property directly or try to do something with modules using `ModuleFinder` and friends.

Comment: I check that out already, but I still have no solution to my issue?

Comment: Consider what Guava does. Don't thing any better solution exists. (https://github.com/google/guava/blob/4f794799aa981eba0000b54004257c0f4fa78b88/guava/src/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.java#L109)

Comment: thanks but that uses URLClassLoader in line 462 (ok for Java 7 and 8) then it falls through to use classpath in line 466

Comment: And that's exactly what I said in my comment. No better solution known. :)